# After merged exe with dll using ilmerge command prompt started with the exe

Tags: dll, exe, ilmerge

I merged my exe (Winforms app) with the Newtonsoft.Json.dll using ILMerge with this code:

`X:\ilmerge\ilmerge.exe /t:exe /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319" /lib:. /out:X:\ilmerge\myexe.exe X:\ilmerge\in\myexe.exe X:\ilmerge\in\Newtonsoft.Json.dll`

but when i start the merged exe it open up with a command prompt, how can i avoid this?

Comment: Wrong target option, use `/t:winexe`.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks now working.